# How do I print a subset of bytes in a large pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

So I have a really large pointer, p, pointing to roughly 40 bytes.

I also know that these 40 bytes enclose ints, chars, and other pointers. I know how to hop across these 40 bytes too.

For debug purposes I want to print out these contents. How do I do that?

For example, lets say I know that at p+16 there is an int and I want to print this int. Is there a way to "print 4 bytes from this address and format that as an int" in C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just cast & dereference.  Assuming you have `p` already set up:

```
int i = *(int *)(p + 16);
printf("%d\n", i);
```

Watch out for potential alignment issues - for example, this code:

```
int i = *(int *)(p + 3);
```

might cause an exception on some processors (assuming `p` is safely aligned for an `int`, that is).  In that case, you'll need to assemble the bytes yourself.  Here's an example assuming a 4-byte integer and 8-bit bytes.  Make sure to watch out for endianness:

```
unsigned char *p;
int bigEndian = p[3] << 24 + p[4] << 16 + p[5] << 8 + p[6];
int littleEndian = p[3] + p[4] << 8 + p[5] << 16 + p[6] << 24;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
printf ("%d", *(int*)(p+16));
```

A better approach might be to make a struct of the structure you're trying to print, if it's something that can be expressed as such. Something like:

```
typedef struct someStruct {
    int field1;
    float field2;
    char field3[8];
    int field4;
} someStruct;
```

Then you can just do something like this:

```
struct someStruct *p = (struct someStruct*)ptr;
printf ("%d", p->field4);
```

Comment: You will need to consider structure padding.  The compiler is free to pop additional bytes in a structure to improve performance.

Comment: Good point. You may need to add a compiler directive to tell it to pack the bytes of the structure, for example.